# Django HttpResponse reason phrase not working in Apache

Tags: django, apache

I have successfully used custom HTTP error status messages using [HttpResponse.reason_phrase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.reason_phrase)

This works well on the development server, however when i deploy to my Apache server(running on debian) the status messages default to those in the HTTP spec. I cannot see the custom messages

Comment: Are you sure you're running Django 1.6 on your server?